# How to install erlang?

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, rhel5, sensu

i'm planing to install sensu monitoring framework. It needs Erlang to work. I'm running RHEL5 and it's not connected to internet. Only option is to download and install the packages. Please help..

Answer (score 1):

I would try to download and install the RPM package `esl-erlang` from [Erlang Solutions](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads/download-erlang-otp) (CentOS tab). It's a single-package installation.

Comment: By the way installation using repository is a good practice for linux distribution with package system. There is some instructions in https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads/download-erlang-otp how to add repository and install erlang.

Answer (score 1):

Install required dependencies:

```
yum install -y openssl openssl-devel ncurses-devel ncurses unixODBC unixODBC-devel make which java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.ppc64le tar gcc build-essential wget
```

Download `erlang` to install `erl` and `escript` binaries:

```
wget erlang.org/download/otp_src_18.3.tar.gz && tar zxvf otp_src_18.3.tar.gz && cd otp_src_18.3 && export ERL_TOP=`pwd` && export PATH=$PATH:$ERL_TOP/bin
```

Configure and build `erlang`:

```
./configure && make && make install
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the erlang source [tar.gz](http://www.erlang.org/download.html) from internet, then compile the source files and install. just like `make` and `make install`.

You can read this link:http://www.erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html