# Python Raspberry Pi 4: How to install erlang?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, erlang, raspberry-pi4, erlang-otp

There was a similar [question almost a decade ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22828509/how-to-install-erlang) and I don't think the solution applies to me.
I am trying to install a new software, and it needs `erlang` software as a support package.

Step1: I downloaded the package as given below: [image]

step2: installing it on the Raspberry Pi 4

I unzipped the downloaded file and this is what I see inside:

[image]

After this, I have no idea how to install it. I don't see any readme file or executable file so I can install it. I appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: A `tar.xz` file is a compressed archive.  Try untaring those `tar.xz` files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to unzip the file. As it's a `.deb` package, you can install it from the command line with `dpkg -i`:

```
dpkg -i esl-erlang_22.1.6-1~raspbian~buster_armhf.deb
```

(Change to the right directory or add a path as required)